# Как вывести нужные данные с массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы, yii2

В общем, есть массив со следующим содержимым:

```
Array
(
    [0] => common\models\references\SQuizQuestion Object
        (
            [topics_id_arr] => 
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id_rec] => 821
                    [name_quest] => Вопрос №4
                    [text_quest] => Текст к вопросу №4
                    [msg_quest] => Сообщение к вопросу №4
                    [random] => 1
                    [dt_up] => 13.06.2017 10:21:17
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [squizqa] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => common\models\references\SQuizQA Object
                                (
                                    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id_rec] => 365
                                            [id_question] => 821
                                            [name_answer] => Второй
                                            [text_answer] => Не правильный
                                            [corr_answer] => 0
                                            [dt_up] => 13.06.2017 10:21:17
                                            [status] => 1
                                        )

                                    [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
                                    [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
                                    [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
                                    [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )
                                )

                            [1] => common\models\references\SQuizQA Object
                                (
                                    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id_rec] => 364
                                            [id_question] => 821
                                            [name_answer] => Первый
                                            [text_answer] => Правильный
                                            [corr_answer] => 1
                                            [dt_up] => 13.06.2017 10:21:17
                                            [status] => 1
                                        )

                                    [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
                                    [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
                                    [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
                                    [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )

            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => common\models\references\SQuizQuestion Object
        (
            [topics_id_arr] => 
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id_rec] => 781
                    [name_quest] => Вопрос №1
                    [text_quest] => Текст к вопросу №1
                    [msg_quest] => Сообщение к вопросу №1
                    [random] => 1
                    [dt_up] => 07.06.2017 11:00:59
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [squizqa] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => common\models\references\SQuizQA Object
                                (
                                    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id_rec] => 321
                                            [id_question] => 781
                                            [name_answer] => Простой ответ
                                            [text_answer] => Правильный ответ
                                            [corr_answer] => 1
                                            [dt_up] => 13.06.2017 10:19:25
                                            [status] => 1
                                        )

                                    [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
                                    [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
                                    [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
                                    [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => common\models\references\SQuizQA Object
                                (
                                    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id_rec] => 361
                                            [id_question] => 781
                                            [name_answer] => Простой ответ
                                            [text_answer] => Не правильный ответ
                                            [corr_answer] => 0
                                            [dt_up] => 13.06.2017 10:19:25
                                            [status] => 1
                                        )

                                    [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
                                    [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
                                    [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
                                    [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                                        (
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )
```

Как мне из этого массива сделать выборку, что бы сначала вывело:

```
Сначала вопрос:
[name_quest] => Вопрос №4
[text_quest] => Текст к вопросу №4
[msg_quest] => Сообщение к вопросу №4

Потом ответы на него:

[id_rec] => 365
[id_question] => 821
[name_answer] => Второй
[text_answer] => Не правильный
[corr_answer] => 0

[id_rec] => 364
[id_question] => 821
[name_answer] => Первый
[text_answer] => Правильный
[corr_answer] => 1

Потом опять вопрос:

[id_rec] => 781
[name_quest] => Вопрос №1
[text_quest] => Текст к вопросу №1
[msg_quest] => Сообщение к вопросу №1

Потом ответы на него:

[id_rec] => 321
[id_question] => 781
[name_answer] => Простой ответ
[text_answer] => Правильный ответ
[corr_answer] => 1

[id_rec] => 361
[id_question] => 781
[name_answer] => Простой ответ
[text_answer] => Не правильный ответ
[corr_answer] => 0
```

Как правильно сделать выборку данных и в цикле на страницу выводить по очереди такие данные?

**Модель:**

```
// Получаем в массив $Question все записи из таблицы SQuizQuestion где id_rec = $Question_id
public function getQuestion($Question_id)
{
    $Question = SQuizQuestion::find()
        ->where(['id_rec' => $Question_id])
        ->all();
    foreach ($Question as $Quest) {
        // Получаем связанные записи из таблицы SQuizQA для каждого вопроса
        $QuestionAnswer = $Quest->squizqa;
    }
    return $Question;
}

public function getSquizqa()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SQuizQA::className(), ['id_question' => 'id_rec']);
}
```

**Контроллер:**

```
// Получаем в массив $Questions все записи из таблицы SQuizQuestion где id_rec = $Question_id
        $Questions = $modelTestSystem->getQuestion($Question_id);
```

Comment: вы его на этапе формирования не правильно делаете, покажите модели

Comment: @madfan41k добавил модель. вроде как все правильно делаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выводит либо все вопросы с ответами, либо, если передан `id` вопроса, то только его:

Контроллер:

```
public function actionQuestions($questionId = null)
{
    $query = SQuizQuestion::find()->with('squizqa');
    $questionId ? $query->where(['id_rec' => $questionId]) : null;

    return $this->render('questions', [
        'questions' => $query->all(),
    ]);
}
```

Во вьюшке `questions`:

```
foreach ($questions as $question) {
    echo $question->name_quest . ' : ' . $question->text_quest; // Вывод вопроса
    // Вывод ответов
    foreach (question->squizqa as $answer) {
        echo '<p>';
        echo $answer->name_answer . ' : ' . $answer->text_answer;
        echo '</p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На выходе вы получаете ассоциативный массив, у которого ключ это Id вопроса, и два вложенных массива, это вопрос и массив ответов.
Вам осталось просто правильно их вывести.
Но это решение не самое правильное, я лишь дал вам результат который вы просили - это массив. Правильнее всего было бы передать $Questions в вид, и там уже правильно все это отобразить

```
public function getQuestion($Question_id)
{

$result = [];

$Question = SQuizQuestion::find()
    ->where(['id_rec' => $Question_id])
    ->all();
if($Question) {
    foreach ($Question as $Quest) {
        $result[$Quest->id_rec]['question'] = [
            'name_quest' => $Quest->name_quest,
            'text_quest' => $Quest->text_quest,
            'msg_quest' => $Quest->msg_quest
        ];

        if($Quest->squizqa) {
            foreach($Quest->squizqa as $answ) {
                $result[$Quest->id_rec]['answers'][] = [
                    'id_question' => $answ->id_question,
                    'name_answer' => $answ->name_answer,
                    'text_answer' => $answ->text_answer,
                    'corr_answer' => $answ->corr_answer,
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
return $result;
```

}

Comment: То есть вы имеете ввиду что полученный массив из этой функции мне надо передать во вью и уже там с ним работать?